# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization without type info

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have json objects representing special case of an object type:

```
interface X {
   Map<String, Object> extraInfo;
}
```

The subclasses are as follows:

```
class Y implements X {
  String foo;
}

class Z implements X {
  String bar;
}
```

Basically the subclasses are differentiated based on the property names foo and bar in the json objects. How can I configure jackson to deserialize these objects ?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work :

```
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Y.class),
           @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Z.class)})
interface X {
  Map<String, Object> extraInfo;
}

@Getter
class Y implements X {
  public Y(@JsonProperty(value="foo") String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  String foo;
}


@Getter
class Z implements X {
  public Z(@JsonProperty(value="bar") String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  String bar;
}
```

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here ?